# can not pass variable in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

I'm trying to pass variable to my partial like that (**app/views/tweets/_tweet.html.erb**) that's also partial

```
<%= render 'tweets/form', :locals => {:message => "hello world"} %>
```

and in my form partial **app/views/tweets/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= @message %>
```

it doesn't print anything and also doesn't show any errors.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes. You're passing a local variable, but are trying to refer to it as an instance variable. Should be this:

```
<%= message %>
```

Comment: ok but when I do

`<% if local_assigns.has_key? :message %>
  <h2>print something</h2>
<% end %>`

it prints nothing

Comment: Because i'm rendering the form in two times and only one time it has parametr :message the other time it is without parameter

Comment: @JakubKohout: well, it must be this version where you don't pass the local. Make sure you do pass it.

Comment: Also, don't use the `:locals` key. Use this: `render 'tweets/form', :message => "hello world"`

Comment: your last comment solved my problem :) thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not @message, it is message.
Use <%= message %>

Comment: ok but when I do

`<% if local_assigns.has_key? :message %>
  <h2>print something</h2>
<% end %>`

it prints nothing